# Is there any specific reason for why some of the error codes are not recording in the alert log?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am working in oracle database and I am new to oracle. Can anyone please tell me why some of the error codes are not getting recorded in the alert log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which error codes are you expecting to see and don't? The alert log is about the database itself rather than, for example, DML operations which users/applications run and can handle the errors from.

Comment: I am looking for the error message in alert log file for the error code ORA-00348.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert log includes the following items:

> 1. All internal errors (ORA-600), block corruption errors (ORA-1578),
>      and deadlock errors (ORA-60) that occur
> 2. Administrative operations, such as CREATE, ALTER, and DROP
>          statements and STARTUP, SHUTDOWN, and ARCHIVELOG statements
> 3. Messages and errors relating to the functions of shared server and
>          dispatcher processes
> 4. Errors occurring during the automatic refresh of a materialized view
> 5. The values of all initialization parameters that had nondefault
>          values at the time the database and instance start

So if your error doesn't come under these sections, that won't be logged in alert log

For more info on [alert log](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/monitoring001.htm)

Comment: Minor note, you can write into Alert log directly using (undocumented) package `dbms_system`, see [How Oracle Manages Diagnostic Traces and Statistics?](http://www.ordba.net/Tutorials/Diagnostic.htm)